# carousel with responsive columns on each "slide" won't go to next slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to show reviews of this business via the carousel method and each slide would display 3 reviews  on large and medium screens but only one on a small screen

for each review, there would be the star rating on top of it and the review below it (god I hope this makes sense).

so each slide would display 3 reviews, the next slide would display 3 reviews, and so on and so forth. But on mobile screen it would only display one review.

I made the stars as an svg image on illustrator and entered the source to it for each image.

**Problem:**

The carousel won't go to the next slide when I click it. I know I got the right plugins b/c there is another carousel on the same page and it is fully functional.

P.S. if my idea is stupid and you have a better idea on how to display the reviews please share. The reviews are not on google or yelp and I've already talked to them about that and having their customers to leave those online and display those instead.

```
 <!--review slider  -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Carousel indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active">
    <div class="container">
      <!--<div class="row">-->
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
        </div><!--end of col-->

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
        </div><!--end of col-->

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
        </div><!--end of col-->

      <!--  </div> end of row-->
    </div> <!--end of container-->
  </div> <!--closing of the active class-->
  <div class="item">
    <div class="container">
      <!--<div class="row">-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
      </div><!--end of col-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
      </div><!--end of col-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <img src="img/5star.svg" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad aliquid, asperiores, commodi culpa dolores ea harum inventore magnam optio repudiandae sunt veniam voluptate. Consectetur id inventore ipsa, sed vero voluptate?</p>
      </div><!--end of col-->
      <!--  </div> end of row-->
    </div> <!--end of container-->
  </div> <!--closing of the item class-->

</div><!--end of the carousel-->

<!-- Carousel controls -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first slide you have the class `active` but it also needs to have the class `item`.  So the wrapper for your first slide should be written like the following and it should work:

```
<div class="item active">
```

Instead of

```
<div class="active">
```

In your question you also wanted to know if you could only display one review at a time at mobile widths with the native bootstrap carousel.  Unfortunately with the bootstrap carousel that is not possible to my knowledge.  It will always show 3 at a time but they will be at full width of the screen so it will cycle all 3 reviews spanning the screens width.  I think if you wanted to use the native bootstrap carousel you could only display one of the 3 reviews in each slide but then you wouldn't see the other 2 reviews ever, or you could write out 2 different carousels and only display one at larger screens and one at smaller screens with the display:none css property at the desired widths.  And then only activate one at a time if you wanted to have them auto slide depending on screen size, but it would require some extra jquery scripting.

Probably your best bet is to check out a third party carousel like [Owl Carousel](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) that will allow you in javascript to set the amount of reviews you want to be shown at different screen sizes.

Here is a plug and play html page for you to play with for owl carousel.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

    <style>
    /*this style is just for demo purposes*/
    .owl-carousel h4{
        text-align:center;
        padding:40px;
        margin:0;
        background:#4DC7A0;
        min-height:40px;
        color:white;
    }
    </style>

  </head>
<body>


<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div><h4>9</h4></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            768:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:5
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i just linked to the cdn files so you could see this working without doing anything.  But I would download the owl carousel files and when you unzip them the required files will be in the dist file.  Just add them to your project and update the path in the css and javascript links.

Anyway hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! In fact, Owl Carousel has been what I exactly needed. I am trying to figure out how to get IT to have multiple items on it's responsive feature (basically what I was exactly trying to do on my original post) but I hopefully I will figure out tonight (kind of doubt it though lol). 
once again, thank you for the help and the amazing recommendation :)

Comment: Its pretty easy to set up if you have it up and running already you just set the amount of slides you want at each screen width in jquery when you initiate the carousel like in this basic example http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html.  If you don't have it set up yet download it and check out the installation documentation here http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-installation.html.  If you have any questions feel free to comment me.

Comment: I got it all working but my biggest has been the nav buttons and the dots. Once I add them everything gets messed up (this includes just copy/pasting their template from their website. I have the owl.theme.default.min.css & owl.theme.min.css linked in the header and my Java script is the very last thing before closing the body tag. 
There is no $(document).ready(function(){ ... });  in the script tag but I added it in the codepen (it probably doesn't need it since it's the only thing in the page but I can be wrong). 
https://codepen.io/jodlue/pen/BWpQBV

Comment: I have just pasted the css files in the codepen. I didn't find it in codepen and if I forked someone else's code then I was afraid they have changed the CSS. But I know my method of loading it on codepen was not correct.

Comment: Your codepen is setup fine except you forgot to load jquery and the owl carousel javascript here is an updated one that is exactly the same except I added them up above where it says settings click on javascript and add the path to the folders I just used a cdn for owl carousels javascript.  https://codepen.io/wamosjk/pen/MpJJrv.  I will update my answer with a plug and play html page just copy and paste it to your text editor and open it in a browser and you can play with it.  So read over my answer again.